# Uninstalling X-Pack and error occurs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I had installed x-pack earlier and used it, but The elasticsearch.stdout log says :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown secure setting
>   [bootstrap.password] please check that any required plugins are
>   installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed
>   settings

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you install X-Pack, bootstrap password is added to **the keystore**. If the `elastic user` does not have a password, the bootstrap is used by default. So, when it is set but don't run elasticsearch with X-Pack, elasticsearch fails!

Considering you uninstalled the X-Pack, I can recommend you remove it from the keystore by running the following command after navigating your [elacticsearch]/**bin** directory:

```
elasticsearch-keystore remove bootstrap.password
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes I had already do that !  But I obtain another error   [2018-06-19T09:23:26,821][WARN ][o.e.c.m.MetaData                                                                                                                                               ] Skipping unknown custom object with type licenses

Comment: Can you please share the entire output of the elasticsearch runtime? There should be more information which may help us understand this new WARN message.

Comment: I don't understand why but I obtain a other error ` [2018-06-19T10:11:55,022][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
[2018-06-19T10:11:55,036][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [SOCdata-11] uncaught exception in thread [main]
[2018-06-19T10:12:55,876][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
[2018-06-19T10:12:55,908][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [SOCdata-11] uncaught exception in thread [main]`

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed log. However, there must be more on your elasticsearch terminal. Would you run it again, and copy-paste what you have on the terminal screen? I need to see the entire output of the runtime.

Comment: I have several nodes, and for the errors, there are 4 cases :  

1. The nodes works correctly

2. Without stdout 

3. This error 

[2018-06-19T10:33:35,507][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
[2018-06-19T10:33:35,529][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [SOCdata-16] uncaught exception in thread [main]

4. And this error 

[2018-06-19T09:23:26,805][WARN ][o.e.c.m.MetaData         ] Skipping unknown custom object with type licenses
[2018-06-19T09:23:26,806][WARN ][o.e.c.m.MetaData         ] Skipping unknown custom object with type ml